# How to prevent unnecessary reconciliation when switching React functional components?

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 React functional components that return very similar JSX except for a few small differences:

```js
function Foo() {
  return <div><h1>Foo</h1></div>;
}
function Bar() {
  return <div><h1>Bar</h1></div>;
}
```

Every 0.5s I switch between them:

```js
function App() {
  const [s, setS] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setS((p) => !p);
    }, 500);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  },[]);
  return <div>{s ? <Foo /> : <Bar />}</div>;
}
```

Since the structure of the page doesn't change (text inside `h1` inside `div` inside `div`) I expect just the text in the `h1` to change, but looks like React deletes the inner `div` and replaces with the other component's (which is [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)).
How do I make React notice that the structure didn't change so it doesn't need to do a replace so high up the DOM?

Comment: Maybe because h1 inside a div is a component as a whole. You may want to declare a separate component for h1 if you want just h1 to change - not sure though.

Comment: what if you give your `div` a `key` attribute as it says in https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal adding a `key` prop doesn't help.